# Python - How to pass all args values in method for unit test?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I'm stuck in a situation.

Below is the illustration of same.

I'm passing the values through argument parse. Values of a, b , c.

Code is -

`initial_foo(args):
**codes**
args.a, args.b are used here.`

If I print `args`, it returns `self.args = argsparse.Namespace(a='hii',b='bye',c='yolo')`. Now if I pass `args` in `initial_foo(self.args)` it automatically picks up the values provided through `args`.

Now, I want to test this `initial_foo(args)` method. So, probably I can do is that setting up the same `self.args = argsparse.Namespace(a='hii',b='bye',c='yolo')` and passing in `initial_foo` method. What if I don't want to use this.

Is there any other solution of the same ?

Anything which we can do through ```**locals() ?

Please let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do. You are trying to pass in variables to your function, right? But you don't want to bundle them in the `self.args` object? The use of argsparse implies you are getting these arguments from the command line, right? So why not call `inital_foo` via `inital_foo('hii', 'bye', 'yolo')`?

Comment: @BlackVegetable I've passed 3 arguments through command line but ```initial_foo(args)``` is only using 2 arguments. So, if I pass args it automatically reads the value of args of the given ```args.a``` and ```args.b``` . Thing is this is just an example. In my code, I'm passing 10 args and ```foo_method``` is using 5 arguments. But my main question is for testing pupose. How to perform that. I know you will help me .thanks!

Comment: As a matter of best practice, you should probably pass the arguments as individual arguments and not as a bundled object to be consumed by each function. It will be less error prone to do: `inital_foo(args.a, args.b)`. Most of the time if you have over, say, 7 arguments to a function, that is a good clue you should refactor to make your functions smaller and require less data passing. I'm not sure I can help you without a real code sample here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are thinking on how to unittest the `initial_foo` without creating an argparse.Namespace object, then you could pass `initial_foo` any object which with properties `'a', 'b', 'c'` and allows `dot` notation call.

`locals()` doesn't work because that gives you a `dict`. dictionary elements are accessed through index (`__getitem__`), not dot operator (`__getattr__`)

You could create a class, with these props and pass in an object of that class.

```
class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
         self.a = a
         self.b = b
         self.c = c

initial_foo(Data(1,2,3))
```

Or pass in a named tuple

```
from collections import namedtuple
data = namedtuple('data', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
initial_foo(data(1,2,3))
```

Anything similar should work too.

Comment: Perfecto!! Thanks.